# Compute the generating functional for the $bc$ theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, conformal-field-theory, correlation-functions, propagator, ghosts

I need the generating functional for the $bc$ CFT, which has $$L=\frac{1}{2\pi}(b\bar{\partial}c + b\partial\bar{c}),$$ so I can compute the correlation function $$\langle b(z_1)c(z_2)\rangle =\frac{1}{z_{12}}.$$
I know that for a scalar field theory, the generating functional is defined as

$$Z[J] = \int D\phi \exp\left\{i\int d^4 x[L+J(x)\phi(x)]\right\}$$

which can be put in a more explicit form by making a change of variables and completing the square. But I can't figure out how to get an analogous expression for the $bc$ theory. I think there must be two sources $J_b$ and $J_c$. Then I have something like

$$Z[J] = \int DcDb \exp\left\{i\int d^4 x[L+J_b(x)b(x)+J_c(x)c(x)]\right\}$$

and I know at some point I'm supposed to complete the square in the exponential to get it in a useful form, but I can't see how to do that here since there are no quadratic terms.

Comment: How there are no quadratic terms? The terms in $L$ are quadratic in the fields. Are you confused because each term mixes the two fields instead of involving a single field?

Comment: Yes that was my confusion. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action is a quadratic form, just one consisting of off-diagonal terms. So you can formally complete the square by writing
\begin{align}
b\bar{\partial}c + bJ_b + J_cc = (b + J_c \bar{\partial}^{-1}) \bar{\partial} (c + \bar{\partial}^{-1} J_b) - J_c \bar{\partial}^{-1} J_b.
\end{align}
This is essentially the same manipulation by which one derives the propagator of the Dirac field.